# Adding block via jQuery

Tags: jquery

We have some block. Ex:

```
<div class="block"></div>
```

and we want to add tag  inside it, so, at the end it would seems like this:

```
<div class="block"><i></i></div>
```

**How to do it with jQuery?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy (:

```
$(".block").append("<i></i>");
```

or

```
$(".block").html("<i></i>");
```

or any of the dozens of [DOM manipulators](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation) offered by jQuery

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.block').append('<i></i>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick way is `$('.block').append('<i></i>');` Although  this add would add it all div with block classes.

You might need a unique id for a invidual div which would then be.

> $('#block').append('');